# Trying to create a different image for each tooltip in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to coding, and creating a line chart that is very simple.

What's not simple is, I want to have an image in each tooltip. I figured out how to have the same image in each tool tip, but I want a different image for each data point on the line. It doesn't need to change when I change the data, and the image has to be connected to the point on the line, and not just the value (for example day 3 might have a value of 10 and day 12 might also).

Has anyone done this, or does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: which language are you using, which library, and please show us your code.

Comment: I ended up doing it in Javascript. Using a switch command.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer